# How to make webGL distort the HTML under it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

I was playing around with this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=glitch#webgl_postprocessing_glitch.

I have a local copy of the example and made the Three.js renderer an overlay by giving it z-index of 999 and passing {alpha: true} to the renderer to make it transparent. Then I pasted a normal html webpage under it with a bunch of `h1` and background-color set to red. So the webpage is positioned right under the canvas. The problem when i do this is that the glitch effects just end up being a bunch of horizontal white lines.

Is it possible for webGL to distort the html view under it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is No. WebGL doesn't have access to any of the underlying/overlaying frame buffers. You could do a transparent overlay of webGL but you can only obscure what is behind it with what you've overlaid. Not actually grab and modify the pixels.

Some day we hope that the underlying buffers will be exposed to webGL in some way... if that was the case, we could do real HTML UI in 3d, and have it work for VR, etc.

The closest I have achieved is embedding css3d objects in a webGL scene by punching through the alpha of the webgl framebuffer to show the HTML elements behind it, by using a transparent object in the THREE.js scene to write transparent values to show through to the background.

If you just want to draw some glitchy rectangles partly transparent on top of your html, that could work though.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, you cannot access anything rendered by the browser for security-reasons.

What you can do is render the html into a canvas (using an [interesting](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation) [svg-trick](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)) and use that canvas as a texture in webgl. There even is [a project called html-gl](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/HTML-GL) that is a full implementation based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a better understanding of how HTML renders, the canvas element where three.js renders is locked under it's own rendering context.

You can distort any HTML Element, but for that you need to understand CSS Custom filters([CSS Shaders](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/03/Introduction-to-Custom-Filters-aka-CSS-Shaders)) and that has nothing to do with Three.js.

Comment: That feature was removed from chrome and webkit (which were the only ones implementing it) sometime around 2013/2014.